# Cut and place part of an illustrator file with exact size

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to add a new part of a nameplate which has multiple names. But every part with a name has an exact size so it can be printed out and cut. How can I select a part of the nameplate and copy it underneath it with the exact same size as the selected area of the nameplate?

Comment: :)) and how are we supposed to guess this without a print-screen of the file?

Comment: You should hit the edit button and explain yourself a bit better. Odds are that when you do you realize you do not need the question anymore.